# WPF Image : Show image from File, how?

Tags: wpf, image, serialization, uri, deserialization

I want to display images in WPF, but using an actual image, instead of using the URL. The reason to this is because i want to Serialize images, so i can carry them around easily. How can i do this, if Image class is Source only? Which means, uses URI . The idea would be very simple: Serialize image, then, when deserialization done, it would load the image onto a controller like Image.
 Is it even possible to, lets say i had the images serialized, then how could i even get their URI, even such a thing even exists? This is very confusing. Hope for some true enlightenment...

I already found many code snippets that show how to serialize/deserialize but honestly i haven't been able to test them out yet, as the initial part of my plan is already on hold. Although, if anyone has a good clean link to it, i'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF doesn't require an actual URI; it requires an instance of `ImageSource` and it happens to include a built-in converter from `string` to `ImageSource` that interprets the string as a URI.

The easiest way to convert your serialized format into an `ImageSource` instance is to put something like the below in an `IValueConverter` and return the `BitmapImage`:

```
BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
bi.BeginInit();
bi.StreamSource = /*your serialized image data in Stream form*/;
bi.EndInit();
```

Comment: That actually helped me a bunch! I got too focused on URI and didn't even pay attention to StreamSource! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

[`Image.Source`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.source.aspx) is **not** a URI, you **can** enter URIs but they are just automatically converted to an [`ImageSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imagesource.aspx) using a `TypeConverter`. So if you want to serialize and deserialize images you can expose a respective `ImageSource` as a property, this can then be set as or [bound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) to the `Image.Source`.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it also helped me comprehend better the first comment!